# Why * characters are not substituted in my sed command?

Tags: bash, sed

I do not understand why this command :

```
echo "type    f(type     titi)" | sed 's/type\(\s+\)/void\1**/g'
```

outputs this :

```
type    f(type     titi)
```

I would expect this :

```
type    **f(type     **titi)
```

I tried to escape * in sed command :

```
echo "type    f(type     titi)" | sed 's/type\(\s+\)/void\1\*\*/g'
```

But the output remains the same.

Comment: `\s` is a PCRE extension. POSIX regular expressions, including both BRE and ERE variants, are not required to recognize it at all.

Comment: ...so, right now, your regex simply *doesn't match*.

Comment: In GNU `sed`, at least, `\s` isn't the problem, but `+`. `type\(\s\s*\)` seems to work fine.

Comment: *Many* platforms have extensions adopted from PCRE, but best not to assume their presence unless known for certain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the right-hand side of the regex is being wrongly-interpreted, but that the left-hand side doesn't match at all.

---

Sticking with [BRE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), we can make this work with:

```
sed 's/type\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/void\1**/g'
```

Note that `\s` has been changed to `[[:space:]]`, and the `+` has been replaced with standard-compliant `\{1,\}` syntax. (With GNU versions of `sed` one could also use `\+` in BRE, but this is an extension rather than standard-mandated behavior).

---

Or, we can switch to [ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) by adding the `-r` argument, in which case we no longer need backslashes around our grouping parens, and `+` is guaranteed to work.

```
sed -re 's/type([[:space:]]+)/void\1**/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sed 's/type\(\s+\)/void\1**/g'` command matches `type`, after that, it matches and puts one or more whitespaces characters into a group, as the escaped round brackets are capturing brackets in POSIX BRE.

All you need to do is use `*` (to match 0 or more whitespaces) instead of `+` (`+` matches a plus symbol), or - if you must match at least one whitespace - `\{1,\}`:

```
echo "type    f(type     titi)" | sed 's/type\(\s*\)/void\1**/g'

echo "type    f(type     titi)" | sed 's/type\(\s\{1,\}\)/void\1**/g'
```

Both give you expected result.